# ViewPager stuck

Tags: java, android

I'm using a view pager on my application with multiple fragment inside, I also disable the my viewpager swipe using these code, but in my layout 'fragment_hr_link.xml' I can swipe it but it got stuck between 2 fragments

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It works fine in some of my fragment but, I'm having problem with this layout, the swipe is working but it got stuck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.hr.HrLinkFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hr_daily_schedule"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Daily Schedule"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#3253F8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hr_daily_time_record"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Daily Time Record"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#3253F8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hr_evaluation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Evalution"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#3253F8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hr_leave_balance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Leave Balance"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#3253F8"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: swiping got stuck but I already disable it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a viewpager which should not be swipable?

Try making your custom viewpager like this:

```
public class SwipeDisabledViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public SwipeDisabledViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeDisabledViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // returning false will not propagate the swipe event
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you could also have a look at the new viewPager2 from android architecture components: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

hope this helps ;-)